# How to detect page language/locale in a Chrome extension content script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, locale, content-script

I would like my [Chrome extension content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) to detect the language or locale of the page's content (not the browser language/locale). I assume there is a method for this in the Chrome extension API, but should I be using standard Javascript libraries instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the Chrome extension method: [`chrome.tabs.detectLanguage(...)`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-detectLanguage). From the description:

> Detects the primary language of the content in a tab.

Answer (score 0):

You could use standard javascript DOM functions to look for a [lang](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.1) attribute on the root `html` element (or possibly the `body` element). But keep in mind that a page might not be entirely in one language, so different elements of the page may be marked up with different `lang` attributes.

Also, if you want to support xhtml, I'd suggest looking the `xml:lang` attribute as well.